# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser (initialization failure)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, struts, noclassdeffounderror, rad

Good day,

I have a web application which have a module to let user to download a report in excel file when click on a button.

However, I have hit this error :

```
[10/10/13 20:21:48:332 MYT] 00000095 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet action: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:176)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
    at com.cv.report.service.impl.ReportServiceImpl.getReport(ReportServiceImpl.java:101)
    at com.cv.report.service.core.AbstractReportExporter.getReport(AbstractReportExporter.java:69)
    at com.cv.report.service.impl.ExcelExporter.exportAsByte(ExcelExporter.java:120)
    at com.cv.report.service.core.AbstractReportExporter.export(AbstractReportExporter.java:53)
    at com.cv.report.service.impl.ExcelExporter.export(ExcelExporter.java:82)
    at com.cv.report.service.impl.ReportService.export(ReportService.java:53)
    at com.cv.ibs.ccweb.report.ReportLastSuccessfulSignOnDateAction.performExport(ReportLastSuccessfulSignOnDateAction.java:121)
    at com.cv.ibs.ccweb.report.ReportAction.executeOther(ReportAction.java:62)
    at com.cv.ibs.ccweb.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:487)
    at com.cv.ibs.ccweb.report.ReportAction.execute(ReportAction.java:88)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:465)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1422)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:505)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

I try to search from internet, but mostly talk about missing jar file in my class path issue.
I checked my file in my environment, I think my jar files should be correct, the following is those jar files :

1. commons-beanutils.jar
2. commons-collections.jar
3. commons-digester-2.1.jar
4. commons-discovery-0.2.jar
5. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
6. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
7. iText-2.1.7.jar
8. jakarta-regexp.jar
9. jasperreports-4.7.0.jar
10. jasperreports-applet-4.7.0.jar
11. jasperreports-fonts-4.7.0.jar
12. jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar
13. jcommon-1.0.15.jar
14. poi-3.8-20120326.jar
15. poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
16. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
17. stax-api-1.0.1.jar
18. xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

I am working with RAD 8.5.5 with Struts framework. Before this, I am working on the same web application in RAD 7.0.

RAD 7.0 is working fine with the button to download the report in excel file. However, when I transfer to RAD 8.5.5, I have hit this error.

Kindly let me know if I provide wrong information.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you post your jrxml code for which you using for styling in your report?

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a failure to load AWT classes (JRStyledTextParser's static init does GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()).

Add -Djava.awt.headless=true to the server Java process to confirm or infirm this possible cause.

Comment: Thanks dada67. I am new to Java, can I know which file I should add this code inside?

Comment: I can't answer that, it depends on your setup/products used/etc.